# Efficiency of sieve of eratosthenes algorithm in c++

Tags: c++

(Keep in mind, I'm a complete beginner to c++)
I have tried to write a sieve of eratosthenes funciton in c++, and it currently looks as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <chrono>

int main() {
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    int max_val = 100000;
    std::vector<int> primes(max_val);
    std::iota(primes.begin(), primes.end(), 0);
    for (int i = 2; i <= primes.size(); i++) {
        int j = i+i;
        while (j < primes.size()) {
            primes[j] = 0;
            j += i;
        }
    }
    std::unordered_set<int> set_primes(primes.begin(), primes.end());
    set_primes.erase(1);
    set_primes.erase(0);
    std::cout << set_primes.size() << "\n";
    auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(stop - start);
    std::cout << duration.count() << "\n|";
}
```

However, this function is very inefficient (generating a set of primes less than 10mil takes around 11 seconds, where my python program can do it in about 4). I'm guessing the issue might lie in me iterating over millions of zeros in my vector when creating the unordered_set. What could I do to improve the efficiency of my program?

Comment: What optimisation flags did you use when compiling in order to produce a program that's worth benchmarking?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm really not familiar with those terms. Could you explain the question please?

Comment: When I tried it, it took 1.6s to generate 10mil. You are probably compiling in debug mode.

Comment: You're right, I was unaware that I was running it incorrectly. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

firstly all divisors of a number(except for itself and 1) are equal or less than sqrt(number), so first of all your first loop should run be from 2 to sqrt(n), secondly, you can start your second loop not from i + i but from i * i (don't want to prove it here, it's not that simple), so the final code is gonna be:

```
int n;
   cin >> n;
   vector<bool> prime (n+1, true);
   prime[0] = prime[1] = false;
   int i = 2;

   while (i * i <= n) {
       if (prime[i])
           for (int j = i * i; j <= n; j += i)
               prime[j] = false;
       i++;
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I have actually edited my code to include most of your suggested modifications (except starting from i*i) since posting the initial question. I'm currently stuck on another problem still related to the computation of this. While the sieve works much faster using vector<bool>, it does mean that I have to manually extract the primes from it by positions of the 1s, and I think I am going about this wrong (iterating through the length of the vector, and adding positions of 1s), since this is taking most of the computation time of my program.